# How to extract classes from .jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I have .jar file. I tried running command *jar xf my.jar* it gave nothing. I tried using JD GUI, but it gave me this message: *Invalid input file '/home/hey/Desktop/my.jar'.*

Does it mean I can't extract classes from this .jar file?

Comment: I tried running command jar -xvf tools.jar, it works. I think your my.jar is corrupted or it isn't stored in jar file format.

Answer (score 22):

If you wish to extract a file from the Jar file, use the following command:

**`jar xf jar-filename  archived-files`**

The **`x`** option indicates we wish to extract files, the **`f`** option indicates **from a jar file**, the **`jar-filename`** is the filename of the jar file to extract from and the **`archived-files`** are the files to extract. 
We can also extract all files by simply not specifying which files to extract:

**`jar xf project.jar`**
**Note:** If it's not Accessible do like as @Legend told, **Open With** *WinRaR* check weather it's a proper **`.jar`** or **`.zip`** file. If it's not opening with winrar there may be problem in **`.jar/.zip`**.

Answer (score 8):

You can open the jar file with winrar, this will show all the class files within, from there, you can drag them all into JD-GUI and decompile them all.

Comment: Archive:  /home/hey/Desktop/my.jar
[/home/hey/Desktop/my.jar]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  /home/hey/Desktop/my.jar may be a plain executable, not an archive
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/hey/Desktop/my.jar or
          /home/hey/Desktop/my.jar.zip, and cannot find /home/hey/Desktop/my.jar.ZIP, period.

Comment: Right click the jar and select 'Open With...' from there, you can select Winrar from your Program Files.

Answer (score 7):

for linux users

```
unzip your.jar
```

Answer (score 7):

How did you create your .jar file?

I just used Dex2Jar on MAC OSX like so -

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/dex2jar-2.0/d2j-dex2jar.sh ~/mobile/pjr.mob.android/obj/Debug/android/bin/classes.dex --force
```

and the resulting file had a permissions issue, so when I went to open it with JD GUI it gave the *"Invalid input fileloader:"* error you mentioned above.

If you do a -

```
sudo chmod +xr ~/Downloads/dex2jar-2.0/classes-dex2jar.jar
```

You will then be able to open it in JD GUI.

Comment: I don't think there is a file named "classes-dex2jar.jar" in that folder. How did u get that?

Comment: Look at the output of the command above when you run it on your machine, my .dex source file is "classes.dex" which automatically becomes ./classes-dex2jar.jar (in the directory you ran the above command).

Answer (score 1):

The answer of WickedW is correct!

```
sudo chmod +xr *.jar
```

then you can open the jar with jd-gui